# Swapping elements in a linked list

Tags: c, list, loops, struct, linked-list

So I'm running into a little problem with my sorting function.
While it's doing what it's supposed to in the second edge case,
the elements get swapped and then swapped back continuously.

The example here happens when Sven(25) and Bob(22) meet.

```
void sortPerson(person *pers, person* newPerson)
{
    if(pers == NULL || pers->next == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is emtpy");
        return;
    }
    person* tempValue;
    person* prev = pers;
    person* curr = pers->next;
    //person* newValue = pers;

    while(prev != NULL && curr != NULL)
    {
        //first edge case
        //adds a new person
        if(prev->age < newPerson->age)
        {
            newPerson->next = prev->next;
            prev->next = newPerson;
               
        }
        //second edge case
        //swapping process when prev age greater than curr age
        //forming a decending order of ages
        if(prev->age > curr->age)
        {
            tempValue = prev; 
            prev = prev->next; 
            prev->next = tempValue; 

            printf("\nPerson age: %d\n", tempValue->age);
            printf("loop test\n");
            printf("%d and %d\n",prev->age, prev->next->age);
        }
        //third edge case
        //if age is the same do nothing
        if(prev->age == curr->age)
        {
            return;
        }
        prev = prev->next;
        curr = curr->next;  
        
    }
}
```

This function returns a new person

```
person* addPerson( person *newPers ){
    return newPers;
}
```

And here is my main if you want to test it yourself

```
int main(){
    person* person1 = construct_person("Max", 20);
    person* person2 = construct_person("Sven", 25);
    person* person3 = construct_person("Bob", 22);
    person* person4 = construct_person("John", 23);
    person* newPerson = construct_person("Markus", 21);

    person1->next = person2;
    person2->next = person3;
    person3->next = person4;
    //person4->next = addPerson(person1, newPerson);
    

   
    //swapPerson(person1);
    sortPerson(person1, addPerson(newPerson));
    printperson(person1);

    free(person1);
    free(person2);
    free(person3);
    free(person4);
    free(newPerson);

}
```

My struct person and constructor

```
typedef struct person person;
struct person{
    char *name;
    int age;
    person *next;
};

person* construct_person(char *name, int age)
{
    person* pers = (person*) malloc (sizeof(person));
    pers->name = name;
    pers->age = age;
    pers->next = NULL;
    return pers;
}
```

I suspect the problem is that my 'prev' struct pointer gets altered throughout the process, but I'd like a second opinion and potential fix.

*Note I'm only freeing it like this because this is testing only and I'm not gonna add more people else I'd done so iteratively.

Comment: Instead of swapping the `prev` and `curr` nodes themselves, why not swap their contents (i.e. the data inside the nodes)?

Comment: Because if I for example create even bigger objects I'd have to switch them out one by one right? For example if I got name, age, adress, id etc.
Or is there a way to bundle them?

Comment: Perhaps simplest if you abstract out the list and node structures from the data. So if a nodes had a pointer to a `person` structure instead of being a `person` structure, it would be very simple (plain initialization and assignment of the structure objects).

Comment: Other than that I recommend you use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement while using pencil and paper to draw the list and the operations you perform on it. Use boxes for the nodes, and arrows for the pointers (including `next` links). When you modify a pointer or link, erase the arrow and redraw it. If you do like that, do the operations done make sense when you see the visual representation on paper? Using pencil and paper is also a good way to start experimenting, before writing code. Make it work on paper, then translate it into code.

Comment: You should post `construct_person` and `person`

Comment: `sortPerson` sounds like a function for sorting a list but it also seems the function inserts a new person. Please explain in further details.

Comment: `addPerson` isn't doing anything. Is that a bug? Should the new person be added by that function instead of doing it in `sortPerson`. This is rather confusing.

Comment: If `person1` isn't head-of-list after sorting, your code has a real problem.... it seems you can't change the head

Comment: It is still Head of the list.
The addPerson was just a test I had a few print functions inside now it just returns
a person construct.
It is indeed for sorting, but I'm kinda new to linked lists and I'm stuck at the swapping elements process. @4386427

Comment: Well, split your code up into simple functions you _do_ understand. If you're swapping nodes, there should be a `swap` function that takes two `person*` and exchanges their positions in the list. Check it works. Write a simple `push_front` and check _that_ works. Write an `insert` at a specific position, and check _that_ works. Then you can write a `find` to get the correct insert position and call `insert`. All of these are standard container operations that should be much easier to write and test.

Comment: @SupEldrix Why do you add a new person in the sort function?

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks:

- The name `sortPerson` is not well chosen. It should better be named `insertPerson`
- You cannot hope to sort a list with just one iteration and a swap here and there during that iteration. If that were possible, you would have invented the most efficient sorting algorithm. So, this cannot work -- at least not always.
- Instead of implementing some sort algorithm (like bubble sort, selection sort, ...), make sure you add *all* persons using that `insertPerson` function. That way you can be sure that the list *into* which a new person is inserted, is already sorted. This way you don't have to swap elements at all. You only have to find the correct insertion point and insert the new person there. So in the main program you should not be fiddling with `next` pointers. Leave that to this `insertPerson` function.
- When a list is empty or just has one person, you should still insert the new person. It makes no sense to not do it when the list is empty (or just has one element).
- The only base case is when you need to insert the person *before* all other persons. In that case the reference to the first person needs to change, as the new person becomes that first person. One way to make that work, is to make the first parameter a call-by-reference. In other words: pass the address of where the first person pointer is stored, so that this pointer can be changed, and the caller will have access to that change.
- I don't see the logic in omitting an insertion when the age of the new person matches the age of a person already in the list. Surely your list should allow Bob and Alice, even when they are both 28.
- There are several other points to make...

Here is a working version. I had to make some assumptions about the code that you didn't share, but the principle should be clear even if your code is different:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct person_s {
    int age;
    char name[100];
    struct person_s * next;
} person;

person* construct_person(char* name, int age) {
    person* p = malloc(sizeof(person));
    strcpy(p->name, name);
    p->age = age;
    p->next = NULL;
    return p;
};

void insertPerson(person** youngest, char* name, int age)
{
    person* newPerson = construct_person(name, age);
    // Even when list is empty, still add it
    if (*youngest == NULL || (*youngest)->age > age) {
        newPerson->next = *youngest;
        *youngest = newPerson;
        return;
    }
    person* prev = *youngest;
    person* curr = prev->next;
    // Search insertion point
    while (curr != NULL && curr->age < age) {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    // Found it:
    prev->next = newPerson;
    newPerson->next = curr;
}

void printList(person* pers) {
    while (pers != NULL) {
        printf("%s is %d years old.\n", pers->name, pers->age);
        pers = pers->next;
    }
}

void freeList(person** pers) {
    while (*pers != NULL) {
        person* temp = *pers;
        *pers = (*pers)->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}


int main(){
    person* personList = NULL;
    insertPerson(&personList, "Max", 20);
    insertPerson(&personList, "Sven", 25);
    insertPerson(&personList, "Bob", 22);
    insertPerson(&personList, "John", 23);
    insertPerson(&personList, "Markus", 21);
    printList(personList);
    freeList(&personList);
}
```